# Issues when binding a variable in ngFor

Tags: angular

How do I two-way bind a variable in ngFor so that it dynamically creates the HTML element depending on the value of the variable?

Here is the fiddle showing what I am trying to do: https://plnkr.co/edit/nmo5zwnSQjTHBk8YxvOJ?p=preview

Initially hello appears 4 times because I have `repeatNumber` initialized to 4. But when I change that value, the Hello output should repeat that many  number of times.

Here is my AppComponent:

AppComponent:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RepeatPipe} from './pipe';

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="5" [(ngModel)]="repeatNumber"/>
        <label>Repeat Number: {{repeatNumber}}</label>
        <div *ngFor='#i of repeatNumber | repeat'>
          Hello
        </div>
      </div>
    `,
    pipes: [RepeatPipe]
})
export class AppComponent{
  repeatNumber: number = 4;
}
```

Here is the CustomPipe which helps in repeating the HTML element:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'repeat'
})
export class RepeatPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(value) {
        return (new Array(value)).fill(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the value from the input is a **string** and your @Pipe function expect a **number**

Here it's the updated **Pipe** :

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'repeat'
})
export class RepeatPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(value) {
        const numberValue = Number(value);

        return (new Array(numberValue)).fill(1);
    }
}
```

And the updated plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/ukNlIa71658vWjrs6Pm5?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot. could you please tell me how you debugged this? the console was not showing an errors.

Comment: It was no error because **new Array('5')** is valid syntax, but creates an Array with the string value of 5, instead of creating 5 elements when the *5* is a number. I added a console.log in your pipe transform to see what is returned by the pipe.

Comment: But the console shows: `[1, 1, 1, 1]` for input 4 even if I don't convert it to a Number. Shouldnt it show `['1', '1', '1', '1']`?

Comment: I see that you updated the plunker with a console.log(). No, for me it's displayed **[1]** every time I insert a value in the input. The **new Array('4'))** returns ['4'] and **['4'].fill(1)** returns [1].